# i'm getting error ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block on ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, filesystems

fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb2

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 
or
e2fsck -b 32768

Comment: Perhaps the output of `lsblk` will help understand what's happening (eg: drive block device order changed)?

Comment: hexdumping /dev/sdb2 and tell what the magic number is actually could help us helping you.